# Sending a Javascript variable to then be used in a PHP script

Tags: php, javascript, sql

is it possible to send a javascript variable in this case the current url to a php script to then insert it into a database? I'm tring to send the current URL to the insert.php file.

I have this JS:

```
 <a href="javascript:(function(){var jsScript=document.createElement('script');
jsScript.setAttribute('type','text/javascript');
jsScript.setAttribute('src', '<?php echo $url?>/insert.php?url='+encodeURIComponent(location.href)+'&amp;title='+encodeURIComponent(document.title));
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(jsScript);
})();">Add!</a>
```

Then I would do PHP:

```
$_GET['url'] = sanitize($_GET['url']);
$_GET['title'] = sanitize($_GET['title']);

mysql_query("   INSERT INTO user (url,title)
                VALUES (
                    '".$_GET['url']."',
                    '".$_GET['title']."'
                )");
```

Am I on the right tracks or have I got this completely wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks about right, pass the javascript variable by building a querystring and sending to the server.

It would be cleaner to use AJAX. You can handle failures and notify the user when the insert has completed.

In [jquery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

```
var param = 'bleh';
var site = 'http://what.com/';

$.ajax({
  url: site+'?param=' + param,
  success: function(data) {
    alert('Data was inserted');
  }
});
```

Comment: using AJAX is cleaner because it sends data back to the PHP script on your server without doing a page reload. you then have to use the AJAX response and some javascript if you want to change the current page based on the response you get back from the PHP script you AJAXed.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is yes. Here's an example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var result = 1;
location.href="page.php?Result=" + result;
</script>
```

Then use $_GET  to get the value of result.

Comment: this is more along the lines of what you are already attempting. it redirects you to the page again but giveing your PHP some GET variables to use during the next page load.